# Python Variables Referecing - unexpected behavior with zip

Tags: python

I really thought I understood Python variable referencing, so I'm confused why this code isn't making the variable "a" be "1":

```
>>> a,b,c = None, None, None
>>> for var, val in zip((a,b,c),[1]):
...     var = val
... 
>>> print a
None
>>> print var
1
```

Can anyone explain what Python is doing here?  Why don't "var" and "a" point to the same place?

Bonus question: What's an elegant way to assign three variables from a list that can have 1-3 items and leave the variables set to None if the list falls short?

Comment: Note that your zip is discarding  b and c since the first list is longer than the second list. is this intentional?

Comment: You're placing the variables in a tuple (a,b,c) which are immutable.  Using a list [a,b,c] may help, but I doubt that it will as `zip` probably just reads the values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can anyone explain what Python is doing here?

It's assigning the value of the variable `val` to the variable `var`. It is not changing `a`. Try the following to see what is happening:

```
>>> a, b, c = None, None, None
>>> print(zip((a,b,c), [1,2,3]))
[(None, 1), (None, 2), (None, 3)]
```

`zip` never sees the variables `a`, `b` and `c`, just the values they are bound to.

Read up on Python's use of variables (names, really) in [Code Like a Pythonista](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names).

> What's an elegant way to assign three variables from a list that can have 1-3 items and leave the variables set to None if the list falls short?

Don't construct variables dynamically. Use a list instead.

```
vars = (lst + [None] * 3)[:3]
```

Then use `vars[0]` etc. Or

```
x, y, z = (lst + [None] * 3)[:3]
```

Comment: The latter form is called "tuple unpacking" and it can be used for funny business like `a,b,c = 10,20,30` or even `a,b = b,a`.

Comment: @Kos: and does some useful error checking to see if the right-hand side has the desired length.

Comment: Thanks the x, y, z = (lst + [None] * 3)[:3]
 is pretty clever.

Answer (score 2):

Variables a, b, c get evaluated to their values when passed to `zip`:

```
>>> a,b,c = None, None, None
>>> zip((a,b,c),[1])
[(None, 1)]
```

Then, in your loop you have not what you expected:

```
for var, val in [(None, 1)]:
    #-- here var is bound to the value None

    var = val
    #-- here var is bound to the value 1

    #print val
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that a's value is None is because you never assigned `1` to `a`. So you would need ensure a is assigned a value.